# Struct and class display value in Visual Studio debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Consider the following simple program (using Visual Studio 2015):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dtClass = new MyDateTimeWrapperClass(DateTime.Today);
        var dtStruct = new MyDateTimeWrapperStruct(DateTime.Today);
        WriteLine(dtClass);
        WriteLine(dtStruct);
        ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyDateTimeWrapperClass
{
    private readonly DateTime _value;

    public MyDateTimeWrapperClass(DateTime value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

public struct MyDateTimeWrapperStruct
{
    private readonly DateTime _value;

    public MyDateTimeWrapperStruct(DateTime value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

The console will report the expected output of the `ToString` method. **However, when in debug mode the output is not the same.**

[image]

I had always thought that Visual Studio used a `ToString()` call to display this value. Yet with structs this appears to not be the case. Could someone explain this behavior? I would appreciate answers which also describe how this value is computed in the first place, as it seems my understanding is incomplete.

## Update: Additional Information

1. This issue does not happen when I use Visual Studio 2013.
2. Hardcoding the `ToString` calls to different values results in normal behavior.

Comment: What's different about the output?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush One prints the date, one prints the date and time.

Comment: I would have bet the same, debugger calls toString() to show value.
Can you try to avoid any WriteLine, and insert an exception in ToString() method of the struct? what happens in debugger?

Comment: I see same `MM/dd/yyyy` format both in debugger and on console also, when I took your code to reproduce. Also in both the cases(class/struct) debugger calls `ToString()` overrides. You can confirm this by putting a `Console.Write(...)` to log some message and when debugger stops on `Console.ReadKey()`, check the console window and you should see the messages printed from within `ToString()` overrides.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ5v6.png) this.

Comment: or also, as a try, implement `ToString()` as `return "I'm a struct";` and `return "I'm a class";`: what happens in the debugger?

Comment: @GianPaolo This results in the the expected behavior. So it seems to be related to the DateTime.ToString(string format) call? Is anyone else able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it and have a workaround - see answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about WHY - but the DebuggerDisplayAttribute could be used for that effect:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992(v=vs.110).aspx < Guide to using
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx < Shows types it can be applied to

Something like this would work:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
public struct MyDateTimeWrapperStruct
{
    private readonly DateTime _value;

    public MyDateTimeWrapperStruct(DateTime value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString() => _value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Use the follow to remove quotes:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ToString(),nq}")]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! This is very helpful and interesting. Because my question is not about how to make this behavior go away, but instead to understand the behavior itself, I've opted not to mark this as an answer.

Comment: NP - glad you found it helpful.  I too would be interested in knowing the why.